# $V\otimes V \simeq \mathrm{Sym}^2V\oplus \bigwedge^2 V$

Tags: linear-algebra, representation-theory

Let $V$ be a complex finite-dimensional vector space. How to prove in a simple fashion that
$$V\otimes V \simeq \mathrm{Sym}^2V\oplus \bigwedge^2 V$$

(I learned this can be seen using representation theory as a decomposition with respect to the action of $\mathrm{Gl}(V)$, can somebody sketch the idea behind this?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write
$$u\otimes v=\frac12 (u\otimes v+v\otimes u)+\frac12(u\otimes v-v\otimes u)$$
Not so bad, right?

Comment: How direct of a proof this is depends on one's formal definition of the symmetric/antisymmetric tensor products.  In any case, it can be said that there are injective linear maps
$$
u \vee v \in \operatorname{Sym}^2V \mapsto \frac 12(u \otimes v + v \otimes u)\\
u \vee v \in \wedge^2V \mapsto \frac 12(u \otimes v - v \otimes u)
$$

Answer (score 1):

We only need to check that the dimensions coincide. Let $n=dim(V)$:

$$ dim(V \otimes V) = dim(V)\cdot dim(V) =n^2. $$

On the other hand

\begin{align*}
dim \left(Sym^2(V)\oplus \bigwedge^2 V\right) 
&= dim (Sym^2(V)) + dim\left( \bigwedge^2 V \right) \\
&= \frac{n\cdot(n+1)}{2} + \frac{(n-1)\cdot n}{2} = n^2.
\end{align*}

Comment: The dimensions coinciding is only enough to give a vector space isomorphism. I suppose the question doesn't ask for a representation theoretic decomposition.

Comment: @MattSamuel Indeed, I understood it as an isomorphism of vector spaces. Therefore I did not rely on representation theory.